# Cargar atributos dinámicamente en objetos

Tags: java, spring-boot

Ando investigando sobre la carga dinámica de atributos con valores por defecto, en un objeto.

Suponiendo el código siguiente:

```
public class ClassA {
  private String stringA;
  private int intA;
  private boolean booleanA;
  private ClassB classb;
}
```

```
public class ClassB {
  private String stringB;
  private int intB;
  private boolean booleanB;
  private Date dateB;

}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de interrogarle y cargar valores a los atributos por defecto según el tipo? Y en caso de que un atributo sea otro objeto de otra clase, inicializar dicho objeto y cargar los atributos de los que disponga dicho objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En java existe una característica muy potente y poco conocida llamada [`Reflection`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html) que te permite examinar y manipular las clases en tiempo de ejecución, utilizar esta característica no es simple pero ya que estas utilizando `Spring` puedes valerte de una clase que facilita mucho el proceso `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils` ya que Spring utiliza mucho esta característica para lograr toda la flexibilidad y dinamismo del framework.

Para el ejemplo utilizare las clases que muestras y una extra, a demás sobrescribí el método `toString` para verificar los valores finales de los atributos, en el ejemplo creare un método llamado `cargarAtributos` que utilizare de forma recursiva:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String stringA;
    private int intA;
    private boolean booleanA;
    private ClassB classb;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassA{" +
                "stringA='" + stringA + '\'' +
                ", intA=" + intA +
                ", booleanA=" + booleanA +
                ", classb=" + classb +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ClassB {
    private String stringB;
    private int intB;
    private boolean booleanB;
    private Date dateB;
    private ClassC classC;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassB{" +
                "stringB='" + stringB + '\'' +
                ", intB=" + intB +
                ", booleanB=" + booleanB +
                ", dateB=" + dateB +
                ", classC=" + classC +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassC {
    private String stringC;
    private int intC;
    private boolean booleanC;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassC{" +
                "stringB='" + stringC + '\'' +
                ", intB=" + intC +
                ", booleanB=" + booleanC +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.util.Date;

public class CargaAtributos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instanciamos la clase a procesar
        ClassA obj = new ClassA();

        // Enviamos el objeto instanciado y el nivel a cero, esta variable
        // es únicamente para imprimir con indentación el resultado y facilitar la lectura en  consola
        cargarAtributos(obj, 0);

        // Imprimimos el objeto para validar que se modificaron los atributos
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

    public static void cargarAtributos(Object obj, int nivel) {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(obj.getClass(), field -> {

            printWithLevel("Atributo: " + field.getName(), nivel);
            field.setAccessible(true);

            // Verificamos el tipo de clase al que pertenece el campo y cargamos el valor por defecto
            if (field.getType() == String.class) {
                // para cargar un nuevo valor pasamos el objeto y el nuevo valor en el metodo field.set
                field.set(obj, "Hola Reflexion nivel " + nivel);
            } else if (field.getType() == int.class) {
                field.set(obj, 10 * nivel);
            } else if (field.getType() == boolean.class) {
                field.set(obj, true);
            } else if (field.getType() == Date.class) {
                field.set(obj, new Date());
            } else {
                // Si no cumple ningún criterio asumiremos que es una clase propia y la instanciaremos y cargaremos a la clase padre,
                // además de ejecutar un proceso recursivo para verificar los atributos del nuevo objeto.
                try {
                    // De esta forma creamos una nueva instancia de la Clase para evitar un NullPointer el verificar la clase de forma recursiva
                    Object newInstance = Class.forName(field.getType().getName()).newInstance();
                    field.set(obj, newInstance);
                    cargarAtributos(field.get(obj), nivel + 1);
                } catch (InstantiationException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Metodo para imprimir los atributos con indentación segun el nivel o profundiad del objeto.
    private static void printWithLevel(String texto, int nivel) {
        StringBuilder indentedText = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < nivel; i++) {
            indentedText.append("---");
        }
        System.out.println(indentedText.append(texto));
    }
}


// Resultado de la ejecución: 
Atributo: stringA
Atributo: intA
Atributo: booleanA
Atributo: classb
---Atributo: stringB
---Atributo: intB
---Atributo: booleanB
---Atributo: dateB
---Atributo: classC
------Atributo: stringC
------Atributo: intC
------Atributo: booleanC
ClassA{stringA='Hola Reflexion nivel 0', intA=0, booleanA=true, 
classb=ClassB{stringB='Hola Reflexion nivel 1', intB=10, booleanB=true, dateB=Tue Nov 23 7:36:07 CET 2021, 
classC=ClassC{stringB='Hola Reflexion nivel 2', intB=20, booleanB=true}}}
```

> Como punto final, tendrías que mejorar la lógica del else en la
> verificación del tipo de dato porque si agregas una tipo de dato que
> no exista en una clase asumirá que es una clase propia que instanciara
> he intentara aplicarle recursividad lo cual generara un error  `java.lang.InstantiationException`.

Comment: Si, eso es lo que buscaba, como duda que me surje, si se usas envolturas de los datos primarios (ejemplo int -> Integer o boolean -> Boolean) ¿serían ignoradas en las primeras condiciones y pasarían a la condiciones ELSE?

Comment: Si, por eso debes de estar seguro de los tipo de datos que vas a manejar porque las envolturas son clases deferentes aunque internamente manejen el tipo primitivo, recuerda marcar la solución como respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Hola @Ismael Garcia Martin creo que lo que estas pidiendo seria algo así:

```
public class ClassA {
  private String stringA { get; set; } = "";
  private int intA { get; set; } = 0;
  private boolean booleanA { get; set; } = false;
  private ClassB classb { get; set; } = new ClassB();
}

public class ClassB {
  private String stringB { get; set; } = "";
  private int intB { get; set; } = 0;
  private boolean booleanB { get; set; } = false;
  private Date dateB { get; set; } = new Date();
}
```

Esta sintaxis la he usado tanto en Java como en C# lo que haces es crear una propiedad ponerle el get; set; para poderla leer y despues si haces = valor, es para decirle que valor tendra pordefecto cuando realizes un new de la clase.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace el código. Puede que al OP (autor de la pregunta) le sea útil, pero otros llegarán a tu respuesta y puede que no comprendan lo que hace. Lee [answer].

Comment: Nunca había visto esa sintaxis. Mas que tocar la clase en sí, y generar constructores sobrecargados, hablo de crear un método al que le pases un objecto y este interroge todos los atributos y objectos y los rellene con valores por defecto (y en caso atributos tipo objecto cree una nueva instancia e interroge a su vez sus atributos y los rellene con mas valores por defecto)

Comment: Creo que esta sintaxis es de C#.